# Input to Choke or Crash Generic Javascript

Tags: javascript, testing, javascriptcore

I'm looking for inputs (probably strings) or events, that are likely to cause problems in Javascript as a language without regard to its running environment.

I'm implementing JavascriptCore in an Objective-C app but I'm not terribly familiar with the language itself. I'm looking for possible inputs that might cause problems e.g. something like a SQL injection attack or problems with text encoding.

I want to set up test to see how my JavascriptCore implementation handles dangerous or garbage inputs and to confirm I understand how to catch errors and exceptions.

A few points:

- The Objective-c side I have covered, I'm just interested in Javascript.
- This is being implemented in a Javascript virtual machine completely independent of any browser, node.js or any other common Javascript environments. It has no dom, no documents, no networking, no file system etc. It's just a blank slate for generic Javascript to run in.

Javascript has been around long enough that any such issues may have long been corrected but I wanted to ask those with more experience with the language itself.